# Source code for a WAMP stack

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Can i get the source code for a WAMP stack installer somewhere? Any help appreciated

Comment: "Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP"

Comment: Which of these do you want? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up a WAMP project on sourceforge of freshmeat or any other open source code hosting site, and get the code from there.

Comment: I recommend the bitnami wamp stack installer set up. It does a lot of the heavy lifting for you https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer